# javascript testing object properties

Tags: javascript

I have a global object MyFruits that can have multiple properties. At a minimum, it has two properties: Apples and Oranges. I need to find out if it has more properties than just these two.

For the moment, I stringify MyFruits, create a new object with just the Apples and Oranges properties and stringify it too and compare the length of both strings. Something like this:

```
var JsonString1 = JSON.stringify(MyFruits);

var test2 = new Object();
test2.Apples= MyFruits.Apples;
test2.Oranges= MyFruits.Oranges;

var JsonString2= JSON.stringify(test2);

alert(JsonString1.length - JsonString2.length);
```

For now, it initially seems like it's working: if MyFruits contains more properties than just the two main ones, the difference of length will be different from 0.

There's the `Object.keys(obj).length` method that can count the number of properties of an object but it's new and not supported in all browsers so I'm not going to use it.

Is this the best way to do it? Let me know if there's a better way.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: See: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: You want to count the number of properties of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of serializing the object, you'd better loop through the object, and check if there's any property which is not `Apples` or `Oranges`:

```
for (var i in MyFruits) {
    if (MyFruits.hasOwnProperty(i) && i !== 'Apples' && i !== 'Oranges') {
        throw 'Not expected!'; // Do something, eg: error_flag=true;break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to see if it has more than just 2 properties just enumerate the properties and see if more than 2 are present.

```
var count = 0;
for (var name in test2) {
  if (test2.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    count++;
    if (count > 2) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (count > 2) {
  // Has more than 2 properties
}
```

Comment: You could also replace the `count` variable with an if statement looking for `name != 'Apples' && name != 'Oranges'`.

Comment: @Dave true, that is another valid way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the enumerable keys of an object, I would consider extending the Object when Object.keys() if not implemented instead of using the JSON object (which isn't available in all major browsers either).

```
if (typeof Object.keys === 'undefined') {

    Object.keys = function (obj) {

        var keys = [];
        for (var property in obj) {
            keys.push(property);
        }

        return keys;

    }

}
```

Now you will always be able to call `Object.keys(yourObject)` and get the list of object keys.

Comment: The only "major browser" which does not support native JSON is IE7-. See also JSON: [Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @RobW So? My statement is still valid. IE7 is, unfortunately, still around and often needs to be targeted by web developers.

Comment: I did not invalidate your statement. I just noted that IE is the only "major browser" (with a market share of approx 3-6% ([3.34](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201202-201202-bar) - [5.93](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2012&month=1) - [4](http://www.getclicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/internet-explorer/))) that doesn't support native JSON.